# Добавить товар в корзину кодом woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Можно ли при нажатии кастомной кнопки **добавить одновременно два и более товаров в корзину** (например по id товара), при этом **сделать на этот "комплект" скидку 5%, или же задать собственную цену этому комплекту** (в крайнем случае сразу же применить купон, созданный заранее) ?

Видел код который добавляет товар в корзину по id, но не видел чтоб была возможность добавления нескольких товаров и работы с ценой/скидкой

```
<a id="buy" href="#">Buy this!</a>
   <script>    
   $('#buy').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      addToCart(19);
      return false;
   });    

   function addToCart(p_id) {
      $.get('/wp/?post_type=product&add-to-cart=' + p_id, function() {
         // call back
      });
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Несколько товаров можете добавить, размножив одну строчку вашего кода:

```
addToCart(19);
addToCart(25);
addToCart(47);
// ну и так далее...
```

Чтобы добавить купон с кодом discount5, например, вставьте такой код в functions.php вашей темы:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'add_coupon' );
function add_coupon() {
    global $woocommerce; 
    $coupon_code = 'discount5'; // код вашего купона
    if ( $woocommerce->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code ) ) return;
    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
        // Здесь перечень товаров, на которые включается скидка
        $autocoupon = array(19, 25, 47);
        if( in_array($values['product_id'], $autocoupon )) {    
            $woocommerce->cart->add_discount( $coupon_code );
            wc_print_notices();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```